# How to set this attribute like the border of label font in LegendPalette of Teechart

Tags: c#, teechart

I'm using the Teechart to draw a colorgrid in VS2012 with C# and I add a tool named LegendPalette as the colorbar in it. My question is that how to let the label of the LegendPalette look normally? The bold attribute of it may be true just as the screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz734.jpg).

I made some attempts. First I set the bold attribute of the label be false, but it doesn't work. So I set the attributes of "LegendPalette1.Axes.Right.Labels.Font.Brush.Visible" and "LegendPalette1.Axes.Right.Labels.Font.Shadow.Visible" be false. Then I set the " LegendPalette1.Axes.Right.Labels.Font.Color" to "Color.White" and it looks like the screenshot[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tfs6.jpg).

So how to hide the attribute like the border of the label?

Comment: Hello Hsu,

Could you confirm which TeeChartFor.Net are you using? The problem you're experiencing isn't appears using latest TeeChartFor.Net Build number  4.1.2016.10260

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks very much for your help ! The version of the TeeChart I use is 4.1.2015.12170. Could you tell me the solution not to display the border ? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would like inform you, the code below works without problems for us using TeeChart For.Net 2015_4.1.2015.12160:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeChart();
}
private void InitializeChart()
{

    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Surface surfa1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Surface(tChart1.Chart);
    tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
    this.Text = tChart1.ProductVersion;
    surfa1.FillSampleValues(50);
    surfa1.UsePalette = true;
    surfa1.UseColorRange = false;
    Steema.TeeChart.Tools.LegendPalette legendP = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.LegendPalette(tChart1.Chart);
    legendP.Series = surfa1;
    legendP.Axis = Steema.TeeChart.Tools.LegendPaletteAxis.laOther;
    legendP.Axes.Right.Labels.Font.Bold = false;
    tChart1.Panel.MarginRight = 20;
    tChart1.Draw();
    legendP.Left = tChart1.Axes.Bottom.IEndPos + 10;
    legendP.Top = tChart1.Axes.Right.IStartPos;
    legendP.Pen.Visible = false;

}
```

The image shows my results:
[image]
Could you please confirm if code above fix the problem you're experiencing? If not, could you modify the code because we can reproduce the problem exactly?